# Grouping and Filtering the last 3 months of data by Start Date , dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
structure(list(Order = c("100003378", "100003378", "100003378", 
"100003378", "100003378", "100003378", "100003378", "100003378", 
"100016566", "100016566"), Op = c(1016, 1017, 1018, 1019, 1020, 
1400, 1500, 9997, 1800, 1850), `Op Desc` = c("SOLDER REWORK IAW 200358984", 
"PP&C REWORK IAW 200358984", "INSPECT IAW 200358984", "QNOTE REVIEW IAW 200358984", 
"WI 1000   Program FPGA / Test CCA", "WI 1400   Vacuum Bake", 
"WI 1500   Quality Inspection", "PP&C Material Movement / Go To Stock", 
"WI1800Test,TempTest,Tune Puck by Sanding", "WI 1850   Bond SAT Wires, As Required"
), `Part No` = c("2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", 
"2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2355805G1", "2353604G1", 
"2353604G1"), WBS = c("G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
"G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01", 
"G-CUST-01", "G-CUST-01"), `Work Cntr` = c("CHRP0000", "CHRP0000", 
"CHRI0000", "CHRP0000", "26502122", "26303014", "26601012", "26801702", 
"26502132", "26203022"), `Actual Start` = structure(c(1576610787.297, 
1578489110.297, 1578493446.18, 1578600321, 1578617121.747, 1578943396.57, 
1580227782.307, 1580417882.567, 1548185774.11, 1580986391.243
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `Actual Comp` = structure(c(1578443159.437, 
1578489164.8, 1578494073.52, 1578600334.077, 1578618039.147, 
1579611732.62, 1580413592.273, 1580417887.177, 1580986384.79, 
1580986425.4), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), 
    Operation_Span = structure(c(21.2080108796308, 0.000630821759502093, 
    0.00726087962863622, 0.000151354165540801, 0.0106180555566593, 
    7.73537094907352, 2.15057831018611, 5.33564830267871e-05, 
    379.636697685186, 0.000395335648898725), class = "difftime", units = "days")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(Order = c("100003378", "100016566"
), .rows = structure(list(1:8, 9:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to use this , but it is not working

```
df_Exciter <- df1 %>% 
  filter(`Actual Start` > "2020-06-01" & Date <"2020-12-01")%>%
  group_by(`Part No`,`Order`) %>%
  arrange(Order,`Actual Start`)
```

Is there a way I can create a function where I can specify the last X months of data I can see ?
I am new in R and I am trying to understand how to use dplyr

Comment: Convert to `Date` class and then try i.e. `as.Date("2020-06-01")`

Comment: There is no column name `Date`

Comment: is there a way to use date and hours?

Comment: In your data, I didn't see the 'Date' column

Comment: `Actual Start` it is the variable that I want to filter

Comment: This should work in the full data `df1 %>% 
      filter(`Actual Start` > as.Date("2020-06-01") & `Actual Start` < as.Date("2020-12-01"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Actual Start` is intended column for both date filters, this should work for you.

```
df1 %>% 
  filter(`Actual Start` > "2020-06-01") %>%
  filter(`Actual Start` < "2020-12-01") %>%
  group_by(`Part No`,`Order`) %>%
  arrange(Order,`Actual Start`)
```

The sample data you provided has zero columns within the filtered time period however.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. I would always recommend to use `clean_names` from the `janitor` library first - this makes the column names easier to use because they do not contain spaces.
2. the column `Date` does not exist in the data you have supplied (you try to use filter on Actual Start and Date - I presume below that you meant `Actual Comp` for the second one).
3. The way you currently subset the columns will not retain any rows - your filter argument is `Actual Start > 2020-06-01`, which no row satisfies. For illustration I have used `2019-06-01` below.
4. You don't have to use `group_by` here (unless you need it for something after this); you can simply use all arguments in the `arrange` command.
5. If you want more information on what each tidyverse command does, consider installing the `tidylog` package and using each function with `tidylog::` before it (e.g. `tidylog::filter()`)

This then gives you:

```r
df_Exciter <- df1 %>% 
  filter(`Actual Start` > "2019-06-01" & `Actual Comp` <"2020-12-01") %>% 
  arrange(`Part No`,Order,`Actual Start`)
```

or including my recommendations:

```r
library(janitor)
df_Exciter <- df1 %>% 
  clean_names() %>% 
  tidylog::filter(actual_start > "2019-06-01" & actual_comp <"2020-12-01") %>% 
  arrange(part_no,order,actual_start)
```